# Download failed from download link <a> tag in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Here is my code for download link

```
    @foreach($downloads as $down)
    <tr>
                        <td>{{$down->name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$down->created_at}}</td>
                        <td>{{$down->Subject}}</td>
                        <td>
<a href="public\documents\{{$down->file}}" download="{{$down->file}}">


                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-download">
                                Download
                            </i>
                            </button>
                        </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
```

This is my code i make download link for download documents but when i click on download button it failed to download.
i retrieve the data from database.I make one section of upload documents and it successfully upload and path on database table and documents in laravel project public\documents 
But it failed to download when i click on upload button

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJa6h.jpg)

Thanks in advance

Comment: With the information provided, I am pretty sure this is because the path you have given within the `< a href='path/to/file'>` is incorrect.

Comment: Then what should i do basically Here  is path of documents  C:\Users\sonuj\blog\storage\app\public\documents Then What should i do can you please code this <a> tag??

Comment: Can you tell me correct path slashes and url??

Comment: You can try it yourself to see if the path is correct or not. Use Inspect Element in the browser to see the complete path to your file that lies within i.e. `path/to/file` in my example. Copy the path url and enter it in the address bar in a new tab of the browser. If your file is accessible, your path is correct otherwise you need to search for the correct path. Also I cant possibly know your path to give the exact answer.

Comment: Sir which url should i use??

Comment: You are saying relative or absolute url should use

Comment: I am talking about the absolute url that starts with `http://your_domain` and ends with the file name you are trying to access

Answer (score 1):

1. Forward slashes aren't used for directories in urls.
2. The web document root should be the public directory.  Therefore, you should never have public as a prefix in your url.
3. You are also using a relative url instead of a root relative url or absolute url which could be problematic depending on where you are displaying this link.